# Reading Excel File from GET Request (Node)

Tags: excel, encoding, decoding

I am trying to grab values from an excel spreadsheet that has been uploaded to a CRM called "Zoho" and the only way to read the file is to download the file through Zoho's own API. However, when trying to download an .xlsx file through the API, the file is encoded and I cannot figure out how to decode it and read the file. The request, when completed, returns a plaintext file with many question marks in it. What is the correct way to decode the file/is there a better way I could be doing this? Ultimately I want to read the value from the file, then make another request to another API to update a value; at no point do I need to download the excel file locally.

Here is the documentation for the Zoho API: https://www.zoho.com/docs/zoho-docs-api.html

Here is a code snippet where I make a request:

[image]

And finally this is what the result looks like:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need a utility to parse and read the excel data(like node-xlsx), your download seems fine.

Comment: @Musa How do I read in the data though? Do I pipe the download then try to parse from there, or should I do something else?